Matrix Equation $X + AX = B$
Solve the matrix equation $X + AX = B$, where $A$ is a $3 \times 3$ matrix, $B$ is a $3 \times 2$ matrix and thus $X$ will be a $3 \times 2$ matrix.
My problem: $X+AX=B$ can apparently be factored to $X(I (3 \times 3) +A) = B$.
How can $X$ be factored to $X \cdot I(3 \times 3)$, as $I$ is a $3 \times 3$ identity matrix and thus does not have the same dimensions.
Basically how can $X(I(3 \times 3)+A)= X + AX$?

Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, e.g., basic help on mathjax notation, mathjax tutorial and quick reference, main meta site math tutorial and equation editing how-to.

It really should be $(I_{3 \times 3} + A)X = B$, not $X(I_{3 \times 3} + A) = B$. The dimensions make sense to me: $A$ and $I_{3 \times 3}$ are both $3 \times 3$, so they can be added, and $I_{3 \times 3} + A$ is also $3 \times 3$. We can therefore multiply it to a $3 \times 2$ matrix like $X$, to get a $3 \times 2$ matrix $B$.

To answer the question you asked: $X$ cannot be factored to $X I_{3,3}$.
On the other hand, it can be factored as $X = I_{3,3} X$, because a $3 \times 3$ matrix (the identity) times a $3 \times 2$ matrix, $X$, gives a $3 \times 2$ matrix.

As far as I understand your question, it should be
$$X + AX = (I_3 + A)X = B.$$
Thus,
$$X = (I_3 + A)^{-1}B,$$
if $I_3 + A$ is nonsingular.
